# Удалить вершину стека и вернуть число лежащее в нём

Tags: c, указатели, структуры, стек

Мне нужно получить значение лежащее на вершине стека и удалить после верхушку.
Не могу понять что я должен прописать в функции `Pop` и `Push` чтобы получить новую вершину стека. логику я "более-менее" понимаю (с натягом), но как прописать синтаксис? пока загадка! не понимаю что куда передаю.

```
struct stack_double {
    double data;
    struct stack_double* next;
};
```

функция Pop и Push

```
void Pop(struct stack_double** top, double *num) {
    if (*top != NULL) {
        struct stack_double *new_ptr_top;
        struct stack_double *temp = *top;
        // temp  -> next
        *new_ptr_top = *temp -> next;
        *num = temp->data;
        temp->data = NULL;  // обнуляем переменные
        temp->next = NULL;  // обнуляем адрес
        free(*top);
        *top = new_ptr_top;
        //*top = *new_ptr_top;
    }
}

void Push(struct stack_double** top, double *num) {
    struct stack_double *ptr_top;
    ptr_top = malloc(sizeof(struct stack_double));
    ptr_top -> data = num;
    if (top == NULL) {
        *top = ptr_top; 
    } else {
        ptr_top -> next = *top;
        *top = ptr_top;
    }
}
```

сама функция main

```
int main() {
    double n;
    struct stack_double *top = NULL;
    // ...
    Push(&top, &n)
    Pop(&top, &n);
    // ...
    printf("%f", n);
}
```

прошу объяснить

условно считаем что оставшаяся часть написана корректно

Comment: Ничего корректного в вашем коле нет, зачем-то передаешь указатель на double, а указатель на структуру по значению, разыменовываешь указатель на структуру и присваиваешь значение указателю.

Comment: добавил амперсанды при передачи в функцию
чутка поменял функции.  VScode больше не ругается. Но понимания не прибавилось!

Comment: `*new_ptr_top = *temp -> next`. Выпишите типы выражений слева и справа от равенства.

Answer (score 1):

Проанализируем код `Pop`. Будем понимать, какие указатели куда указывают.

Аргумент `struct stack_double** top` указывает на указатель, который находится в функции `main`. Этот указатель указывает на новую структуру, созданную функцией `Push`.

```
Pop : top -> main : top -> struct stack_double
```

А со звёздочкой это уже значение `main : top` и оно равно указателю на первую структуру

```
( Pop : *top == main : top ) -> struct stack_double
```

После вызова функции `Push` у вас он должен указывать на новую структуру и пройдёт дальше.

```
if (*top != NULL) -> OK
```

Вы создаёте себе указатель `struct stack_double *temp = *top;` с именем `temp` и так как `*top` указывает на верхнюю структуру он также на неё указывает.

```
temp -> struct stack_double
```

Запись `*new_ptr_top = *temp -> next;` неправильная. Так как вы переменной `new_ptr_top` не присвоили никакого адреса. Со звёздочкой это означает присваивание структуры неизвестно куда из следующей структуры, которая может быть направлена даже на нулевой адрес. Будет крах памяти.

На самом деле вам нужно было просто скопировать адрес.

```
new_ptr_top = temp -> next;
```

Запись данных по указателю `*num = temp->data;` верная. Указатель `Pop : num` указывает на переменную в `main : n`. И данные, которые хранились в верхней структуре запишутся в переменную `main : n`.

```
Pop : *num -> main : n
```

Обнуление верхней структуры обычно не используют, но для безопасности данных иногда требуется. Обнуляем данные верхней структуры `temp->data=0;` а не `NULL` как у вас и указатель `temp->next = NULL;` *Оптимизация компилятора эти обнуления вычеркнут вообще.*

Освобождаем выделенную память структуре с помощью `free(*top);` или можно для понятности `free(temp);`

Запись `*top = new_ptr_top;` меняет указатель вершины на новый. То есть `Pop : top` указывал на указатель `main : top`.

```
Pop : top -> main : top
```

И после этого переменная `main : top` будет иметь значение `new_ptr_top`.

Исправляем ошибки

```
void Pop(struct stack_double** top, double *num) {
    if (*top != NULL) {
        struct stack_double *new_ptr_top;
        struct stack_double *temp = *top;
        new_ptr_top = temp -> next; // была ошибка памяти
        *num = temp->data;
        temp->data = 0 ;  // обнуляем переменные число а не указатель
        temp->next = NULL;  // обнуляем адрес
        free(*top);
        *top = new_ptr_top;
    }
}
```